# Arduino Uno [Using Assembly] - toggling LED Module using joystick

Tags: assembly, arduino, atmega

New to Arduino and trying to make a program that will toggle an LED module connected to pins 5,4 and 3 of PORTB (13,12 and 11 on the board).

The joystick has a connection to ground and a connection, from SW to pin 7 of PORTD (7 on the board).

The idea is to use assembly programming to do this. This is the program I have made so far (it may be very wrong as I'm learning as I go)

## Update

I have tweaked my code and fixed some things. The Setup part runs and turns on the blue LED when I remove the apploop part. However, the apploop component doesn't work and the red LED is not triggered when I toggle the joystick. Have tried looking at other examples but haven't been able to fix it so far

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

```
   #include "m328pdef.inc"
.global main
.EQU Red_Pin, 17
.EQU Green_Pin, 16
.EQU Blue_Pin, 15
.EQU Led_Port, PORTB
.EQU Switch_Pin, 11
.EQU Switch_Port, PORTD
main:
appSetup:
; Init the 3 output RGB LED's
; in
in r16, Led_Port
; sbr
sbr r16, 0b11111111
; out
out DDRB, r16


; Init the input switch, configure with internal pull up resistor

; in
in r24, DDRD
; cbr
cbr r24, 0b10000000
; out
out DDRD,r24

; in 
in r24, Switch_Port

; sbr
sbr r24, 0b11111111

; out
out Switch_Port,r24


; Turn on the Blue Led to indicate Init is done!

; sbi

sbi Led_Port,3

appLoop:

; Switch pressed = Red Led on

; sbis
sbis Switch_Port, 7

; sbi
sbi Led_Port, 3
; Switch not pressed = Red Led off
; sbic
sbic Switch_Port, 7

; cbi
cbi Led_Port,3

; rjmp appLoop ; keep doing this indefinitely

rjmp appLoop
```

Comment: `sbi` takes a port number (not register) as first argument.

Comment: Ever looked how a compiler would do the job? (see what `avr-objdump` can do for you). You can start with plain avr-gcc and ignore the arduino layer. And remove that tag :)

Answer (score 0):

```
in r16, Led_Port  // <-- should be in r16, DDRB
; sbr
sbr r16, 0b11111111
; out
out DDRB, r16
```

read from PORTB, write to DDRB. Suspicious. Why all bits are set if only 3 are used as outputs?

```
in r24, DDRD
cbr r24, 0b10000000
out DDRD,r24
```

By the way, to change single bit in registers 0...31 (all PINx, DDRx, PORTx in ATmega328P are in this range) you can use `sbi` and `cbi` instructions. E.g.:

```
cbi DDRB, 7 // clear 7th bit of DDRB
```

```
; in 
in r24, Switch_Port
; sbr
sbr r24, 0b11111111
; out
out Switch_Port,r24
```

Again, why all 8 bits are set if you need only one?

```
; Turn on the Blue Led to indicate Init is done!
sbi Led_Port,3

...

; Switch pressed = Red Led on
sbi Led_Port, 3
```

So, bit 3 of the Led_Port (PORTB) is red? Or blue?

There is a mess in your code. Named constants mixed with immediate values. If you use some named constants. Example:

```
.EQU LED_RED_pinno, 5
.EQU LED_BLUE_pinno, 3
...

; Turn on the Blue Led to indicate Init is done!
sbi Led_Port, LED_BLUE_pinno

...

; Switch pressed = Red Led on
sbi Led_Port, LED_RED_pinno
```

Also:

```
; sbis
sbis Switch_Port, 7
; sbi
sbi Led_Port, 3
```

`sbis` skips next instruction, if the bit 7 in `Switch_Port` is set. `Switch_Port` equals to `PORTB`, and it has its bit 7 is always cleared (unless you write 1 to it).

To check the state of an input port, you need to read `PINx` (not `PORTx!`) register. In this case it should be:

```
; Switch pressed = Red Led on
sbis PINB, 7  // (sic!)
sbi Led_Port, 3

; Switch not pressed = Red Led off
sbic PINB, 7 // (sic!)
cbi Led_Port,3
```